# get the arrays value inside another array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an array's values which is already looped in `$each`, here's the jQuery loop's code:

```
$.each(data.re, function(index, value) {
                  console.log(this);
                  setTimeout(function(event) {
                    var $items = 'my values goes here '+value.thumb+'';
                          $grid.append( $items );
                  }, duration / 2 * index);
              });
```

And here's the print of my json array (data.re)

```
Object {
id: 133,
thumb: "http://localhost/test.jpg",
ingr: Array[5]}
id: 133
ingr: Array[5]
0: Object
rcp_ingr_single: "test 1"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
rcp_ingr_single: "test 2"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

`ingr` has 5 arrays inside with same key(rcp_ingr_single), and i have trouble getting the values of the keys.
Could you help me out how to get the values since it's already in the loop?

Comment: Provide sample of real data structure. Can copy it from response body in dev tools newwork

Comment: @charlietfl why it does matter? i just don't know how to get the value of ingr array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your intent from your description and it's also hard to understand the data structure based on what appears to be output copied from the Chrome console, but...

I think you want the values that are found in `data.re[x].ingr[y].rcp_ingr_single`. Your existing $.each loop seems to be iterating the `re` array, so `value` inside the loop maps to `data.re[x]`.

In your code, at the point where you reference `value.thumb`, you could reference:

```
value.ingr[y].rcp_ingr_single
```

To obtain the `y`'th `ingr` item (and the `rcp_ingr_single` member of that item). You probably want another loop inside there to iterate those `ingr` items (but you haven't said what you want to do with those items, or shown any example attempt to guide us, so I don't want to guess any further).

**EDIT**:

You clarified your intent in a comment, so here is example code showing the rcp_ingr_single being appended to the "$grid" (whatever that happens to be). I arbitrarily made up the formatting - you should rearrange as required:

```
  $.each(data.re, function(index, value) {
    console.log(this);
    setTimeout(function(event) {
      var $items = 'my values goes here ' + value.thumb;
      $.each(value.ingr, function(index, value) {
        $items += '</br>' + value.rcp_ingr_single;
      });
      $items += '</br>'
      $grid.append($items);
    }, duration / 2 * index);
  });
```

Here's a plunker too: https://plnkr.co/edit/eKsnQ5c2Xp2PrPzWw0Hj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! So you understood correctly, I need to get all the rcp_ingr_single values where inside each array, and print them inside `$items`. I'm a newbie to jQuery and struggling to fix this.